# Is there any way to search the media of a certain country?

Tags: google-search

Sometimes I'd like to know "What does Israeli media say about Ireland?" or "Has  Sepak Takraw ever been mentioned in Canadian media?" or "Does British media provide much coverage of Australian Rules Football?" and other such questions.* Is there any way to wrangle answers to such questions out of Google? (Or possibly out of another decent search engine?)

Google News doesn't seem to work, because (a) it covers *current* news only, and (b) most of what I'm thinking of are more fluff pieces than actual *news*.

---

* I really don't know why these things interest me, but they do.

Answer (score 1):

I would Google search by site. For example, find an online newspaper site (or other media site) for the country whose media you want to check (my random selection timesofisrael.com), and search on the keyword you are interested in. In your example,

> Ireland site:timesofisrael.com

Settings -->Advanced Search will accomplish the same thing.

If you want to widen your search you could search sites on the country domain (for example "Ireland site:.ca) though this won't catch sites using generic .com domains.